# Find minimum values in ArraysList Object

Tags: java, android

I'm french beginner in Java and Android developpement. Actually I try to make an exercice but i'm stuck...

I have an ArrayList (playersList2) of Object (Players), Players contains string (mFirstName) and int (mScore))

I made some try with collection, loop, and I read lot of documentation and forum but i don'f find a solution however I'm pretty sure it's easy

```
    Players players = new Players(mFirstname, mScore);

    mPreferences = getSharedPreferences(PREF_PLAYERS_LIST, MODE_PRIVATE);
    String fromJsonPlayersList = mPreferences.getString(PREF_PLAYERS_LIST, null);

    Gson gson = new Gson();
    ArrayList<Players> playersList2 = gson.fromJson(fromJsonPlayersList, new TypeToken<ArrayList<Players>>()
    {
    }.getType());

    /* find the weakiest players/

    if  //mscore is bigger than weakest players
    {//remove the weakest players and add this one
    }*/
```

I want to find the minimum mScore in the entire ArrayList to make a condition(if current mScore > minimal playersList2 replace weakiest PlayersList2 Players by current Players)

Thanks a lot

Comment: Actually , you have to iterate over the array list using such object as iterator.There are a few way to iterate over the array - using loops (for , while) and using iterator object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest solution for you is to use a simple for-loop, something like:

```
Players minScorePlayer = playersList2.get(0);
for (Players player: playersList2) {
   if (player.getScore() < minScorePlayer.getScore()) {
      minScorePlayer = player;
   }
}
//now minScorePlayer variable contains the reference to a player with the minimal score
```

P.S. this code is intended to give you the general idea. You may have to adjust it for your needs.

Comment: thanks for yours answers, actually it's seem working !

Answer (score 1):

Assuming this is your Players class:

```
    public class Players {
    String mFirstName;
    int mScore;

    public Players(String mFirstName, int mScore){
        this.mFirstName = mFirstName;
        this.mScore = mScore;
    }
}
```

this would get your lowest score:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    ArrayList<Players> playersList2 = new ArrayList<>();

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
        Players player = new Players("name", i);
    }

    Players lowestScore = playersList2.get(0);

    for (Players p: playersList2) {
        if (p.mScore < lowestScore.mScore){
            lowestScore = p;
        }
    }

    System.out.println(lowestScore.mScore);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways to do this.

Before we start with the solution, let us have the Player class here:

```
class Player {
    String firstName;
    int score;

    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }

    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }

    public int getScore() {
        return score;
    }

    public void setScore(int score) {
        this.score = score;
    }
}
```

One way is to loop through the ArrayList and finding the player with minimum score and other is using Stream API to find the player with minimum score.

Solution1: Here we loop through the List to find the Player with minimum score.

```
List<Player> players = new ArrayList<>();

// .. add some players in the List players

Player weakestPlayer = null;
int minScore = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
for(Player player : players) {
    if(player.getScore() < minScore) {
        weakestPlayer = player;
    }
}
```

Solution2:
It is a bit complex solution using Stream API in java.

```
Player weakestPlayer = players
        .stream()
        .min(Comparator.comparing(Player::getScore))
        .orElseThrow(NoSuchElementException::new);
```

This solution uses Java Stream API to find player with minimum score. Here we are using the min() method to find the player with minimum score. The min() method needs a comparator which will help it compare the scores and decide which player is having the minimum score. The below line of code fetches the comparator for int.

```
Comparator.comparing(Player::getScore)
```

If the List is empty then it will throw an error since it could not find the player with minimum score.